# MySQL Primary Key declaration

Tags: mysql, reference, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have to create a tally table where the tally is generated by getting the sold price from booksavailable and newarrivals , the cost price from publisher and subract the two to get a profit/loss table.

How do I declare the tally table with the syntax for referring the above mentioned keys?
what should the primary key of this table be?
The table needs to display the corresponding bookid ie bid and the profit/loss brought from that book.

Code used :

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKSAVAILABLE( 
BID VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY, 
        TITLE    VARCHAR(50),
        AUTHOR    VARCHAR(40), 
        CATEGORY VARCHAR(40), 
        PRICE VARCHAR(10),
        AVAILABLE VARCHAR(5)
);

CREATE TABLE NEWARRIVALS(
        BID VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY, 
        TITLE VARCHAR(50), 
        AUTHOR VARCHAR(40), 
        CATEGORY VARCHAR(40),
        PRICE VARCHAR(10), 
        AVAILABLE VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE PUBLISHER( 
        PID VARCHAR(5), 
        BID VARCHAR(5),
        PRIMARY KEY(PID,BID), 
        NAME VARCHAR(40), 
        CONTACT VARCHAR(10),
        UNITS VARCHAR(40), 
        SOLDAT VARCHAR(10)
);
```

Comment: Are new arrivals available? Or are they still to arrive?

Comment: The primary key should probably be book id.

Comment: The new arrivals are available.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you are doing some programming,i.e. PHP, you may change your MySql design to a simpler one. Particularly, calculating the inventory and profit is a very simple task. Also you may use a joint table for the publisher, why? Because, with current design, you will end up having redundant data for publisher. Since one publisher can have many books there is no need to store, publisher name, address, in each publisher field for each book. I recommend adding a date column to booksavailable which gives you the opportunity to simply differentiate the newarivals from the available books. This will remove the newarrivals table which is very identical to booksavailable and so redundant.

Also you may add a table called ORDER to put your purchases in it, buy subtracting the amount you sold the book from the amount the actual book price you may calculate your loss/profit. Also, if you're using InnoDB engine in mysql which gives you the ability to define foreign keys, there is no need to call each table primary key with different name, they all can be named ID. I recommend the following desing:

[image: mysql workbench diagram]

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE TALLY( 
ID int PRIMARY KEY,
BID VARCHAR(5) , 
PRICE_PROFIT_LOSS INT)
```

anyways in all ur tables all the attributes for price are varchar() while they shud be int or bigint..

also it is nice to declare BID , PID as int instead of varchar() and in reality the tally table is not required since it is basically a calculation .. but if u need one then the structure cud be like the above.. the PK for the tally table is just an autogenerated ID in reality..